# Why does yocto skip my recipes?

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to add a new layer for my freescale imx6 board. It depends on meta-fsl-arm layer.

The layer is added to bblayers.conf. But when I build machine imx6dlwisehmi, the linux-imx6-autorock_3.10.17.bb won't be used as virtual/kernel. The recipe is skipped in bitbake-layers show-recipes output. Also the warning:

```
WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_autorock '^/opt/yocto/sources/meta-autorock/'
```

Any help is appreciate, thanks.

Here is my layer's details:

file tree

```
meta-autorock/
|
+--conf/
|  |
|  +--machine/
|  |  |
|  |  +--imx6dlwisehmi.conf
|  |
|  +--layer.conf
|
+--recipes-kernel/
   |
   +--linux/
      |
      +--linux-imx6-autorock-3.10.17/
      |  |
      |  +--wisehmi/
      |     |
      |     +--defconfig
      |
      +--linux-imx6-autorock_3.10.17.bb
```

layer.conf

```
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "autorock"
BBFILE_PATTERN_autorock = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_autorock = "4"
LAYERVERSION_autorock = "3"

LAYERDEPENDS_autorock = "core fsl-arm"
```

imx6dlwisehmi.conf

```
require conf/machine/include/imx-base.inc
require conf/machine/include/tune-cortexa9.inc

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-imx6-autorock"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx6-autorock ?= "3.10.17"

SOC_FAMILY = "mx6:mx6dl"
```

linux-imx6-autorock_3.10.17.bb

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx.inc
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-dtb.inc

SUMMARY = "Linux kernel for Autorock boards"

SRC_URI = "git@git.autorock.com:i-mx6/fsl-linux.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH} \
           file://defconfig"

LOCALVERSION = "-1.0.1_ga+yocto"
SRCBRANCH = "imx_3.10.17_1.0.1_ga"
SRCREV = "45add5da5831d3f6ddd1db0160797080a8adf9a5"
DEPENDS += "lzop-native bc-native u-boot-mkimage-native"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(wisehmi)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the problem:

the COMPATIBLE_MACHINE should be imx6dlwisehmi to match the machine name.